# User is getting mobile is incompatible alert when he is trying to download it from play store

Tags: android, react-native

I have published an application in android which is built using react-native and its `miniumSDKVersion=29`. One of the user raised a concern saying that he is getting an alert with title ***mobile is incompatible*** while he is trying to download it.He is using **huawei p10** mobile. Is that issue is popping up due to incompatible OS with my application?

Comment: Huawei has their own version of the Android SDK called HMS Core. Similar, but not the same, and from what I understand the cause of much frustration.

If you use Google Play Services in any capacity, you can't count on those working on Huawei, would need to make them work with HMS

Comment: @hcl2000., Yes you are absolutely correct. Huawei does not support Google Play services due to trade restrictions and If an app uses the GMS services then we can't show it in google play store. But in my case I have got response from user that he is running on android 9 which is the max OS version that will be supported by huewai p10 where as my app's min SDK version is 10.

Answer (score 0):

The user had faced this issue because Huawei P10 supports only till android 9 version. My app only supports from android 10 (miniumSDKVersion=29). So that's why he is getting the error. Also, As @hcl2000 mentioned in the comment, GMS (Google Play) services are not compatible with Huawei android phones and If your app is using the service then it is better to use HMS Core library which is similar to Google Play Services SDK.